# wildcard ssl installation on domain

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl

I have had a wildcard SSL cert installed on my linux server by one of our IT guys.

When i access my site now with just http in the url bar everything works fine and the site shows up

When i access my site via this link: https://mydomain.co.uk the site automatically redirects to https://mydomain.co.uk/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.

Any ideas why this could be? I read into that it could be DNS and caching issues along with propagation. I have left it a few days now and is still the same. I have restarted apache on the server, and also had the certificate re-installed multiple times.

It was also suggested to upgrade to the latest version of cpanel/whm which i did and made no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as im pulling my hair out! 
Thanks, Dan

Comment: If you're willing to give the domain name publicly, and post your `httpd.conf`, we may be able to help.  Otherwise, I find it a bit of a guessing game.

Comment: Don't see how this is a DNS or SSL issue, sounds like a webserver configuration issue.

Comment: @MadHatter the url is https://indigoapps.co.uk/ how can i access the httpd.conf to post it?

Comment: @mgorven i am only posting what i have found on cpanel forums

Comment: danyo, it depends on what distro you are using on your server.

Comment: server is using centos

Comment: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and the contents of `/etc/httpd/conf.d`.  I'm not sure about the propriety of putting that all in your question (it might be quite long) so you might want to investigate one of the pastebin-like services.

Answer (score 2):

A new Apache `VirtualHost` would have been created for the HTTPS instance, you're being redirected to the default page because this virtual host has no content yet. HTTP and HTTPS virtual hosts are separate and distinct in Apache.

Depending on what you want to do with the HTTPS version, you could copy all the HTTP settings over, or possibly change the `DocumentRoot` to point at the same place that the HTTP version uses.

I think this should be relevant and help you figure out the paths:
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/InsideVHost

There are no evident issue with DNS or the cert itself, it even has a SAN of "indigoapps.co.uk" so it will work with or without "www".